# Problems getting data using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just learning Angular JS.
I'm trying to populate the scope variable with the result of an ajax database call.
The ajax call returns a propper json object(an array) but I cannot get $scope.contentType to output on my HTML page.

Can anyone see any reason this should not work?

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    var allMyData;
    $scope.title = 'Content Types List';

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/angularJS/dbServices.cfc?method=getContentTypes"
    })

    request.done(function(data){
        allMyData = data.DATA;
        console.log(allMyData);
        $scope.contentTypes = allMyData;
    })

    request.fail(function(){
        console.log('fail');
    })
}])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your `$scope` isn't updating on the view is because you are changing that value outside the `$digest` cycle. You need to use AngularJS' built-in [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

You can get more information/documentation in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using jQuery ajax which is not triggering angular digest. You can fix it with:

```
 request.done(function(data){
    $scope.apply(function() {
      allMyData = data.DATA;
      console.log(allMyData);
      $scope.contentTypes = allMyData;
    })
})
```

However, this is not the best practice. Instead you should 1) use $http service as mentioned in other answer 2) Move the entire logic to a separate service 3) use a high-level interface provided by ngResource